# c# "if" statement not working . Checking all variables are null

Tags: c#, .net

I have this XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<message>
 <success/>
  <bookings>
   <booking>
     <rooms>
      <room roomCode ="101" uniqueId="abc">
      <stays>
        <stay usedfrom="9:30" usedto="10:30" quantity="1" Price="62.5" rateCode="1"/>
      </stays>
      <extras>
        <extra from="9:30" to="10:30" unitPrice="5.5" extraCode="coffee" quantity="1" inclusive="0"/>
      </extras>
      <guests>
        <guest firstName="John" lastName="Doe" title="MR" ageRange="0"/>
      </guests>
    </room>
    <room roomCode ="Brd" uniqueId="xyz">
      <stays>
        <stay usedfrom="13:30" usedto="15:30" quantity="1" unitPrice="60.0000" rateCode="RACK"/>
      </stays>
      <guests>
        <guest firstName="Jean" lastName="Doe" title="MRS" ageRange="0"/>
      </guests>
    </room>
  </rooms>
</booking>
```

and i'm trying to run a check to make sure its in the correct format (ie certain elements are present).
The code I have been using is

```
XmlNodeList Successful = doc.GetElementsByTagName("success");
XmlNodeList Bookings = doc.GetElementsByTagName("bookings");
XmlNodeList Booking = doc.GetElementsByTagName("booking");
XmlNodeList Rooms = doc.GetElementsByTagName("rooms");

if ((Successful != null) && (Bookings != null) && (Booking != null) && (Rooms != null))
{
    //do something
}
else
{
    //do something else
}
```

This ALWAYS works thought.

If I change the one of the values to

```
XmlNodeList Rooms = doc.GetElementsByTagName("NoSuchElement");
```

(which does not exist in the XML) it still "works".

Can someone point out what I've done wrong (I've tried removing the outer brackets from the "if" statement, but this did not change the outcome).

Thanks

Comment: When you say "This ALWAYS works though" do you mean it always executes the `do something` code?

Comment: By the way - an XmlNodeList will not be `null` even though it is empty. Have you tried checking the count of nodes in the list instead?

Comment: You are checking to see if the XmlNodeList is null, not if it contains any elements.  `if (Successful.Count > 0 && ...)`

Comment: Literally solvable by using the debugger or the documentation. Let this be a lesson, eh?

Comment: @GeraldOakham a valuable lesson - in C# any collection object can be not `null` but also be empty!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `oc.GetElementsByTagName("NoSuchElement");` is never null.

As per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dc0c9ekk(v=vs.110).aspx), if no element exists, it returns en **empty collection** which is not null.

You have to check the `Count` of the result.

something like :

```
if (Successful.Count() != 0 && ...)
```

or

```
if (!Successful.Any() && ... )
```

Answer (score 4):

As opf the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dc0c9ekk(v=vs.110).aspx):

> An XmlNodeList containing a list of all matching nodes. If no nodes
>   match name, the returned collection will be empty.

The method can´t return `null`, but an empty list. So check for this instead:

```
if(theNodeList.Any()) { ... }
else { /* error */ }
```